# Detect in Linux Bash if USB drive is unmounted and mount it automatically

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, external-hard-drive, mount

My USB drive is plugged in to a server with Ubuntu system and constantly unmounts itself for no known reason.
I want to write a script in Bash which will be run frequently by cron.
My question is how to check using Bash if a drive is mounted or not and if it is unmounted, mount it automatically?

Comment: `constantly unmounts itself for no known reason` doubt that the cron idea is a good one; i'd rather spend more time in trying to actually fix the problem

Comment: It can be an issue with electricity and this happens roughly once a day. When someone informs me I have to log in to the server and mount the  drive again. So automatic check and mount would solve this mostly.

Answer (score 0):

If the disk normally appears as e.g. "diskLabel" in a subfolder to /media/ then you can detect it like this:

```
$ if [ -d "/media/$USER/diskLabel/" ] ; then echo "Mounted" ; else echo "not Mounted" ; fi
```

The above mounting -style happens automagically when you connect e.g. a USB-device.
When you unmount it `lsblk` still will list it; assuming it still has power.

A device with power and a (e.g. /dev/sdb1) partition can be remounted (in the same manner as happens automagicallly, above) using

```
$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdb1;
```

Comment: But I have a directory /media/storage/ only it is empty because the drive has unmounted itself, so this command will not work, I think.

Comment: A mounted disk will appear as a directory/folder e.g. "disklabel", if that folder doesn't exist then the device isn't mounted (Tested here, just a few minutes ago).